# document.getElementsByClassName breaking jQuery class selector caused by Prototype Override

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict, getelementsbyclassname

Problem occurs in IE6 (probably all browsers pre-dating document.getElementsByClassName).
Using jQuery 1.6 with Prototype 1.5

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // Prototype will claim the '$' namespace so give jQuery '$j' instead.
   $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="../js/prototype.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

The problem is discussed here: http://randomous.com/forum/topic.php?id=916 (see 2nd post) and here: http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-pre-prototype-16

Essentially Prototype creates document.getElementsByClassName in browsers the predate that function (it is natively supported by most browsers nowadays).

However jQuery also checks for the existence of document.getElementsByClassName, and when it finds it, it assumes it's getting the native implementation; but really it's getting Prototypes implementation which doesn't behave as jQuery expects.

I have tried A LOT of tricks to resolve this but none work. [ trying to tell jQuery document.getElementsByClassName is undefined, trying to stop prototype from claiming document.getElementsByClassName, etc. ]

The application is old (hence old prototype) and unfortunately will run mainly on IE6 & IE7 (yes, FML).  I'm trying to use the latest jQuery since that's where I'm comfortable and I need to add lots of crazy UI controls to the app - combobox autocomplete dragdroppy madness.... basically I do need jQuery.

The end result here is I get errors anytime I use jQuery's class selector - $('.someClass')

Any thoughts here?  I thought I was decent with javascript but this is killing me.

Comment: can you show some code u tryed, and maybe make a fiddle of it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when class selector without any tag was called, e.g. `$('.myClass')`
resulted error while `$('div.myClass')` worked well. I replaced `$('.myClass')` with `$('*.myClass')` and it started working

Answer (score 0):

This answer may seem a bit simple, but, update prototype to latest. They abandoned that awful decision: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/getElementsByClassName

And I realize you may be supporting an app you yourself didn't build, but I'd also say that if you have the option in the future, never choose a framework that screws with the ability of other frameworks to do feature detection.

Faking native functionality should be considered harmful. I'm looking at you, prototype.